# SCP a file between two remote servers without prompting for password

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, scp, remote-server

Scenario:

I have 3 systems, 1. Managing system 2. Datawarehouse 3. Client System

I have credentials for all 3 servers available with me. I am taking client credentials(IP, username and password) from user and then I need to trigger a command to copy a file available on remore datawarehouse to remote client system directly from my managing system.

Server M(Managing System), Server D(Datawarehouse) Server C(Client System)

A file at D:/home/file.txt needs to be copied to C:/home/ from M in one single command without any password prompt and password should be provided for both servers in command itself.

Command I am using:

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p "clientpassword" scp -P [ClientPort-22] -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@D:/home/filex.txt root@C:/home/
```

I am not sure how and where I can put password and port for server D. Here I am assuming I can not use keygen as password for client is entered by user in runtime.

Comment: I mentioned that credentials for client C are taken at runtime from users, hence I can not have pre configured.

Answer (score 0):

Configure key based password less authentication between D and C. and triggering the command you mentioned will get your job done.

This will help for doing that : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: As I mentioned password is taken at run time, I would need to commands: 1. Configure key based password authentication 2. Actual SCP. I can not have it configured before hand.